# UUIDs in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to setup my first Rails3 project and, early on, I'm running into problems with either `uuidtools`, my `UUIDHelper` or perhaps callbacks.  I'm obviously trying to use UUIDs and (I think) I've set things up as described in [Ariejan de Vroom's article](http://ariejan.net/2008/08/12/ruby-on-rails-uuid-as-your-activerecord-primary-key/). I've tried using the UUID as a primary key and also as simply a supplemental field, but it seems like the `UUIDHelper` is never being called.

I've read many mentions of callbacks and/or helpers changing in Rails3, but I can't find any specifics that would tell me how to adjust. Here's my setup as it stands at this moment (there have been a few iterations):

```
# migration
class CreateImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :images do |t|
      t.string :uuid, :limit  => 36
      t.string :title
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
  ...
end

# lib/uuid_helper.rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'uuidtools'

module UUIDHelper
  def before_create()
    self.uuid = UUID.timestamp_create.to_s
  end
end

# models/image.rb
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UUIDHelper

  ...
end
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you declaring another before_create method in your Image model? If so, you'll be overriding the one in the UUIDHelper module. You'll want to either declare the callback a different manner, or call super in the callback in your image model.

Edit: Maybe change the helper to look something like this:

```
module UUIDHelper
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      before_create :set_uuid

      def set_uuid
        self.uuid = UUID.timestamp_create.to_s
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the only callback of any sort that's being executed at the moment. For the sake of extensibility, I'll definitely make a change once I get this issue figured out and fixed. I didn't realize that a callback in a helper would be overwritten that way, but I guess it makes sense.

Comment: I continue to be disappointed that Rails doesn't offer UUID support natively and Rails3--at least in its current state--doesn't appear to even support the only reasonable "hack" I've found. There is some good information in this response, so I'm going to mark it as the answer unless/until something better comes along.

Answer (score 5):

If you get an error "NoMethodError (undefined method `timestamp_create' for UUID:Class)", then change the contents of the set_uuid method to:

`self.uuid = UUIDTools::UUID.timestamp_create().to_s`

I believe this is necessary for more recent versions of the uuidtools gem.

Answer (score 1):

I also noticed you're missing the `:id => false` in your `create_table`. Check out the example from Ariejan's article a little more closely:

```
create_table :posts, :id => false do |t|
  t.string :uuid, :limit => 36, :primary => true
end
```

Additionally, I prefer the `UUIDTools::UUID.random_create.to_s` to the timestamp version. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I had to specify the primary key in my model to make it work at the controller level.

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UUIDHelper
  set_primary_key :uuid

  ...

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I outline a working UUID example in this question:

[Is COMB GUID a good idea with Rails 3.1 if I use GUIDs for primary keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747145/is-comb-guid-a-good-idea-with-rails-3-1-if-i-use-guids-for-primary-keys)

Obviously you can rewrite `set_uuid` any way you want--you don't have to use COMB GUIDs.

Credits:  adapted from https://github.com/boriscy/uuidrails3/blob/master/lib/uuid_helper.rb referenced in
[using UUID as primary key in rails and polymorph relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654533/using-uuid-as-primary-key-in-rails-and-polymorph-relationships).
Also found an example at 
https://github.com/belucid/Recent-Updates/blob/884624e433cdffd63abd24b3bdb516a5d1596173/lib/uuid_helper.rb.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider avoiding the use of string types to store your UUID, as it will make lookups super-slow.  There is an ['activeuuid' gem](https://github.com/jashmenn/activeuuid) that looks promising (uses binary storage).