# using UUID as primary key in rails and polymorph relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, uuid, polymorphism

I'm creating a rails 3 application that will be decentralized and I need to use **UUID** as ***primary key*** for my tables, what would be the best gem, plugin for the Job. I also would like to know if it is possible to make in **ActiveRecord** polymorphic relationships without using the polymorphicable_type column for it, given the case that I'm using UUID.

**I have created a demo** http://github.com/boriscy/uuidrails3 that uses UUID as keys, you should check the module UUIDHelper inside lib/ and also all the migrations. There is no need to add a primary key in the database, just an index, because primary keys verify uniqueness of the field, but we don't need that with UUID.

Comment: OK, so what would be the criteria for choosing which table contains the record with the UUID 12345?

Comment: when you use UUID as keys by default you do polymorphic relationships, try some JOINS and you will see you can make a join with any table.

Comment: i checked out your app from the link you provide. question: if you're using uuids for your primary how do you deal with malformed uuids passed to your finders?

Comment: @Boris, thanks for the sample app.  I adapted and extended to create COMB GUIDs and am asking for input on whether that is a good idea:  [Is COMB GUID a good idea with Rails 3.1 if I use GUIDs for primary keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747145/is-comb-guid-a-good-idea-with-rails-3-1-if-i-use-guids-for-primary-keys).

Comment: I have found this article which is really fine http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/how-to-start-using-uuid-in-activerecord-with-postgresql/ for using postgreSQL which right now is my default database.

Answer (score 7):

Put [this file](http://alexmaccaw.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/acts_as_guid/lib/uuid.rb) in the lib directory, and add this as an initializer:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :uuid

  before_create :set_uuid

  def set_uuid
    self.uuid = UUID.generate(:compact)
  end
end
```

As for the relationships, vlad is right that ActiveRecord needs to know which table a record is in to find it. If you want this kind of functionality, try something else like MongoMapper.

Comment: I think I can use id instead of uuid, it would be the same anyway. That would be more convinent.

Comment: Yes, but in that case make sure you change the id column in your migrations to a string (or wider integer field).